# How to run perl test without t/*.t structure(t/sub_folder/*.t)

Tags: perl, testing, makefile, module-build, test-more

I try to gather my code and manage my perl project via Makefile.PL or Build.PL, everything goes well and I got the correct test result with TAP format. But I'd like to make some sub folders under t/ folder to gather different test file, then I found that when I run `make test`, `./Build test` or `prove`, they say `no tests`. Is there any way to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

It's up to the build module(s) to tell Test::Harness which files to run, so that's the documentation you need to look in. If you're using ExtUtils::MakeMaker, for example, you can search for RECURSIVE_TEST_FILES to find the relevant bit.